# No input file specified. (NGINX + php-fpm) [Centos 6.4]

Tags: nginx, php, centos

Всем добрый вечер. Мучаюсь с рядом ошибок:

1. No input file specified.
2. 502 Bad Gateway (при попытке перехода в phpmyadmin)

   [root@GS ~]# php -vPHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Nov 22 2013 10:59:29)Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP GroupZend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies    with eAccelerator v0.9.6.1, Copyright (c) 2004-2010 eAccelerator, by eAccelerator

***Часть конфига, относящаяся к phpmyadmin***

```
    location /phpmyadmin/ {        #alias /hdd/site/site/phpmyadmin/;        root /hdd/site/site/;        index index.php index.html index.htm;            location ~ \.php$ {                try_files $uri =404;#               root /hdd/site/site;                fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php-fpm.sock;                fastcgi_index index.php;                include fastcgi_params;                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;                fastcgi_ignore_client_abort off;            }            location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {               root /hdd/site/site/phpmyadmin;            }    }}
```

**Конфиги:**

php.ini --> http://pastebin.com/1SSWvi96

Nginx.conf --> http://pastebin.com/AGPehUMG

Php-fpm.conf --> http://pastebin.com/2ihR6vm2

www.conf --> http://pastebin.com/vxu0Gd8M

**Конфиг домена:**

cubeworld.conf --> http://pastebin.com/e32kittT

**Логи:**

cubeworld_error.log (NGINX) --> http://pastebin.com/4m0AJudT

error.log (php-fpm) --> http://pastebin.com/wNR0jyhE

---

---

---

При 502-ой ошибке (phpmyadmin), в Логах NGINX появилось:

```
2013/12/04 12:06:35 [error] 21984#0: *3 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 195.131.87.194, server: site.ru, request: "GET /pma/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/tmp/php-fpm.sock:", host: "site.ru"
```

В логах php-fpm:

```
[04-Дек-2013 12:06:34] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 22007[04-Дек-2013 12:06:34] NOTICE: ready to handle connections[04-Дек-2013 12:06:35] WARNING: [pool www] child 22008 said into stderr: "[Wed Dec  4 12:06:35 2013"[04-Дек-2013 12:06:35] WARNING: [pool www] child 22008 said into stderr: "] [notice] EACCELERATOR(22008): PHP crashed on opline 61 of PMA_fatalError() at /hdd/site/pma/libraries/core.lib.php:231"[04-Дек-2013 12:06:35] WARNING: [pool www] child 22008 said into stderr: ""[04-Дек-2013 12:06:35] WARNING: [pool www] child 22008 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV) after 1.059212 seconds from start[04-Дек-2013 12:06:35] NOTICE: [pool www] child 22029 started
```

Comment: Но у вас же в логах error.log явно же написано /hdd/host/mcsu/cubeworld.su/index.php (Нет такого файла или каталога)

Comment: С этим разобрался. Осталась ошибка с PHPMyAdmin (502). Обновил первый пост (под чёрточками)

Comment: Ну опять же  PHP crashed on opline 61 of PMA_fatalError() at /hdd/site/pma/libraries/core.lib.php:231 , что то там не так, попробуйте обновить ваш phpmyadmin на любую другую версию.

Comment: Ничего не скачивая нового - 2013/12/04 14:23:15 [error] 24020#0: *85 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 195.131.87.194, server: site.ru, request: "GET /pma/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/tmp/php-fpm.sock:", host: "site.ru"

Comment: Ну а fpm лог при этом запросе?

Comment: [04-Дек-2013 14:23:15] WARNING: [pool www] child 24048 said into stderr: "[Wed Dec  4 14:23:15 2013"[04-Дек-2013 14:23:15] WARNING: [pool www] child 24048 said into stderr: "] [notice] EACCELERATOR(24048): PHP crashed on opline 73 of PMA_URL_getCommon() at /hdd/site/paxgame/site/pma/libraries/url_generating.lib.php:237"[04-Дек-2013 14:23:15] WARNING: [pool www] child 24048 said into stderr: ""[04-Дек-2013 14:23:15] WARNING: [pool www] child 24048 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV) after 103.436014 seconds from start[04-Дек-2013 14:23:15] NOTICE: [pool www] child 24083 started

Comment: Ну вот же опять f PMA_URL_getCommon() at /hdd/site/paxgame/site/pma/libraries/url_generating.lib.php:237 , Скачайте вы его заново. Не может php-fpm  интерпретировать ваши файлы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге проблема оказалась именно в php-eaccelerator. Отключил его, и всё заработало! Но я хотел бы его оставить..